# Oracle MERGE and prepared statement

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, prepared-statement, insert-update

I have a backup utility, workig on restore section. This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE "SBOOKS"."DEV_CORPUS" 
   (    "CORPUSID" NUMBER(9,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CORPUS_NAME" VARCHAR2(768 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CORPUSLASTSYNC" DATE, 
     PRIMARY KEY ("CORPUSID")
```

In restore class I would like to look for a primary key in table, if it exists then update the row, if not then insert a row.
now the problem is I need to pass the  parameters from the class (they do not exist in any table), how can I do this? what is your suggestion? using preparedstatment or what? and how? please give examples or links to sources.

more info:
I am using oracle sql developer and java netbeans.

**EDIT:** 
     I am trying this in command window:

```
  MERGE INTO dev_corpus a  
  USING (SELECT corpusid, corpus_name, corpusdesc, corpusimageids, rocf1, rocf2, rocf3, rocc1, rocc2, rocc3, corpusactive, corpusrunfrequency, corpuslastrun, corpuslastsync, rocsettingid, corpusaffinity, corpusterms, corpusdomain FROM dual WHERE corpusId = 1000156 AND corpus_name = 'sahar' AND corpusdesc = 'sahaaaaa' AND corpusimageids IS NULL AND rocf1 IS NULL AND rocf2 IS NULL AND rocf3 IS NULL AND rocc1 IS NULL AND rocc2 IS NULL AND rocc3 IS NULL AND corpusactive IS NULL AND corpusrunfrequency IS NULL AND corpuslastrun IS NULL AND corpuslastsync IS NULL AND rocsettingid IS NULL AND corpusaffinity IS NULL AND corpusterms IS NULL AND corpusdomain IS NULL) incoming 
  ON (a.corpusid = incoming.corpusid )  
  WHEN MATCHED THEN 
  UPDATE SET corpusid = incoming.corpusid , corpus_name = incoming.corpus_name , corpusdesc = incoming.corpusdesc , corpusimageids = incoming.corpusimageids , rocf1 = incoming.rocf1 , rocf2 = incoming.rocf2 , rocf3 = incoming.rocf3 , rocc1 = incoming.rocc1 , rocc2 = incoming.rocc2 , rocc3 = incoming.rocc3 , corpusactive = incoming.corpusactive , corpusrunfrequency = incoming.corpusrunfrequency , corpuslastrun = incoming.corpuslastrun , corpuslastsync = incoming.corpuslastsync , rocsettingid = incoming.rocsettingid , corpusaffinity = incoming.corpusaffinity , corpusterms = incoming.corpusterms , corpusdomain = incoming.corpusdomain 
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
  INSERT (corpusid, corpus_name, corpusdesc, corpusimageids, rocf1, rocf2, rocf3, rocc1, rocc2, rocc3, corpusactive, corpusrunfrequency, corpuslastrun, corpuslastsync, rocsettingid, corpusaffinity, corpusterms, corpusdomain) 
  VALUES (incoming.corpusid, incoming.corpus_name, incoming.corpusdesc, incoming.corpusimageids, incoming.rocf1, incoming.rocf2, incoming.rocf3, incoming.rocc1, incoming.rocc2, incoming.rocc3, incoming.corpusactive, incoming.corpusrunfrequency, incoming.corpuslastrun, incoming.corpuslastsync, incoming.rocsettingid, incoming.corpusaffinity, incoming.corpusterms, incoming.corpusdomain)
```

this is the real table:

```
CREATE TABLE "SBOOKS"."DEV_CORPUS" 
   (    "CORPUSID" NUMBER(9,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CORPUS_NAME" VARCHAR2(768 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CORPUSDESC" VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE), 
    "CORPUSIMAGEIDS" VARCHAR2(768 BYTE), 
    "ROCF1" FLOAT(63), 
    "ROCF2" FLOAT(63), 
    "ROCF3" FLOAT(63), 
    "ROCC1" FLOAT(63), 
    "ROCC2" FLOAT(63), 
    "ROCC3" FLOAT(63), 
    "CORPUSACTIVE" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "CORPUSRUNFREQUENCY" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "CORPUSLASTRUN" DATE, 
    "CORPUSLASTSYNC" DATE, 
    "ROCSETTINGID" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "CORPUSAFFINITY" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "CORPUSTERMS" VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE), 
    "CORPUSDOMAIN" NUMBER(3,0), 
     PRIMARY KEY ("CORPUSID")
```

throws me this error:

```
Error at Command Line:2 Column:644
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "CORPUSDOMAIN": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

.

I dont know what I am missing. Do u have any idea?

Thanks!

**EDIT2:**
finally  this works in comand win:

```
MERGE INTO dev_corpus a
  USING (SELECT 1000156 corpusid, 'sss2' corpus_name, 'sahaaaaaar' corpusdesc, null corpusimageids, null rocf1, null rocf2, null rocf3, null rocc1, null rocc2, null rocc3, null corpusactive, null corpusrunfrequency, null corpuslastrun, null corpuslastsync, null rocsettingid, null corpusaffinity, null corpusterms, null corpusdomain FROM dual) incoming 
  ON (a.corpusid = incoming.corpusid )  
  WHEN MATCHED THEN 
  UPDATE SET corpus_name = incoming.corpus_name , corpusdesc = incoming.corpusdesc , corpusimageids = incoming.corpusimageids , rocf1 = incoming.rocf1 , rocf2 = incoming.rocf2 , rocf3 = incoming.rocf3 , rocc1 = incoming.rocc1 , rocc2 = incoming.rocc2 , rocc3 = incoming.rocc3 , corpusactive = incoming.corpusactive , corpusrunfrequency = incoming.corpusrunfrequency , corpuslastrun = incoming.corpuslastrun , corpuslastsync = incoming.corpuslastsync , rocsettingid = incoming.rocsettingid , corpusaffinity = incoming.corpusaffinity , corpusterms = incoming.corpusterms , corpusdomain = incoming.corpusdomain 
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
  INSERT (corpusid, corpus_name, corpusdesc, corpusimageids, rocf1, rocf2, rocf3, rocc1, rocc2, rocc3, corpusactive, corpusrunfrequency, corpuslastrun, corpuslastsync, rocsettingid, corpusaffinity, corpusterms, corpusdomain) 
  VALUES (incoming.corpusid, incoming.corpus_name, incoming.corpusdesc, incoming.corpusimageids, incoming.rocf1, incoming.rocf2, incoming.rocf3, incoming.rocc1, incoming.rocc2, incoming.rocc3, incoming.corpusactive, incoming.corpusrunfrequency, incoming.corpuslastrun, incoming.corpuslastsync, incoming.rocsettingid, incoming.corpusaffinity, incoming.corpusterms, incoming.corpusdomain)
```

but this in java class nooot works in update cases, but if it is an insert case it will work. In case of update it will not throw any error it just freezes untill I delete the record from DB, then it inserts it, so no update!. Do you find something wrong in this code?

```
preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement("MERGE INTO dev_corpus a " +
                              "USING (SELECT ? corpusid, ? corpus_name, ? corpusdesc, ? corpusimageids, ? rocf1, ? rocf2, ? rocf3, ? rocc1, ? rocc2, ? rocc3, ? corpusactive, ? corpusrunfrequency, ? corpuslastrun, ? corpuslastsync, ? rocsettingid, ? corpusaffinity, ? corpusterms, ? corpusdomain FROM dual) incoming " +
                              "ON (a.corpusid = incoming.corpusid ) " +
                              "WHEN MATCHED THEN " +
                              "UPDATE SET corpus_name = incoming.corpus_name , corpusdesc = incoming.corpusdesc , corpusimageids = incoming.corpusimageids , rocf1 = incoming.rocf1 , rocf2 = incoming.rocf2 , rocf3 = incoming.rocf3 , rocc1 = incoming.rocc1 , rocc2 = incoming.rocc2 , rocc3 = incoming.rocc3 , corpusactive = incoming.corpusactive , corpusrunfrequency = incoming.corpusrunfrequency , corpuslastrun = incoming.corpuslastrun , corpuslastsync = incoming.corpuslastsync , rocsettingid = incoming.rocsettingid , corpusaffinity = incoming.corpusaffinity , corpusterms = incoming.corpusterms , corpusdomain = incoming.corpusdomain " +
                              "WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN " +
                              "INSERT (corpusid, corpus_name, corpusdesc, corpusimageids, rocf1, rocf2, rocf3, rocc1, rocc2, rocc3, corpusactive, corpusrunfrequency, corpuslastrun, corpuslastsync, rocsettingid, corpusaffinity, corpusterms, corpusdomain) " +
                              "VALUES (incoming.corpusid, incoming.corpus_name, incoming.corpusdesc, incoming.corpusimageids, incoming.rocf1, incoming.rocf2, incoming.rocf3, incoming.rocc1, incoming.rocc2, incoming.rocc3, incoming.corpusactive, incoming.corpusrunfrequency, incoming.corpuslastrun, incoming.corpuslastsync, incoming.rocsettingid, incoming.corpusaffinity, incoming.corpusterms, incoming.corpusdomain)");
```

thanks!

Comment: It's not clear if you're using MySQL or Oracle. Are you using one or the other? Or both? If you're using Oracle you need `MERGE` and if you're using MySQL you need `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY`. As for syntax problems, I find it's best to work out the query in the command window, then when it's looking good you can implement it in the Java code.

Comment: @Ed Gibbs: sorry my bad, oracle sql developer. plz see the edites code above.

Answer (score 5):

Finally this works!, so here is the query for SQL command:

```
MERGE INTO dev_corpus a
  USING (SELECT 1000156 corpusid, 'sss2' corpus_name, 'sahaaaaaar' corpusdesc, null corpusimageids, null rocf1, null rocf2, null rocf3, null rocc1, null rocc2, null rocc3, null corpusactive, null corpusrunfrequency, null corpuslastrun, null corpuslastsync, null rocsettingid, null corpusaffinity, null corpusterms, null corpusdomain FROM dual) incoming 
  ON (a.corpusid = incoming.corpusid )  
  WHEN MATCHED THEN 
  UPDATE SET corpus_name = incoming.corpus_name , corpusdesc = incoming.corpusdesc , corpusimageids = incoming.corpusimageids , rocf1 = incoming.rocf1 , rocf2 = incoming.rocf2 , rocf3 = incoming.rocf3 , rocc1 = incoming.rocc1 , rocc2 = incoming.rocc2 , rocc3 = incoming.rocc3 , corpusactive = incoming.corpusactive , corpusrunfrequency = incoming.corpusrunfrequency , corpuslastrun = incoming.corpuslastrun , corpuslastsync = incoming.corpuslastsync , rocsettingid = incoming.rocsettingid , corpusaffinity = incoming.corpusaffinity , corpusterms = incoming.corpusterms , corpusdomain = incoming.corpusdomain 
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
  INSERT (corpusid, corpus_name, corpusdesc, corpusimageids, rocf1, rocf2, rocf3, rocc1, rocc2, rocc3, corpusactive, corpusrunfrequency, corpuslastrun, corpuslastsync, rocsettingid, corpusaffinity, corpusterms, corpusdomain) 
  VALUES (incoming.corpusid, incoming.corpus_name, incoming.corpusdesc, incoming.corpusimageids, incoming.rocf1, incoming.rocf2, incoming.rocf3, incoming.rocc1, incoming.rocc2, incoming.rocc3, incoming.corpusactive, incoming.corpusrunfrequency, incoming.corpuslastrun, incoming.corpuslastsync, incoming.rocsettingid, incoming.corpusaffinity, incoming.corpusterms, incoming.corpusdomain)
```

and here is the java code using pstmt:

```
preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement("MERGE INTO dev_corpus a " +
                              "USING (SELECT ? corpusid, ? corpus_name, ? corpusdesc, ? corpusimageids, ? rocf1, ? rocf2, ? rocf3, ? rocc1, ? rocc2, ? rocc3, ? corpusactive, ? corpusrunfrequency, ? corpuslastrun, ? corpuslastsync, ? rocsettingid, ? corpusaffinity, ? corpusterms, ? corpusdomain FROM dual) incoming " +
                              "ON (a.corpusid = incoming.corpusid) " +
                              "WHEN MATCHED THEN " +
                              "UPDATE SET a.corpus_name = incoming.corpus_name , a.corpusdesc = incoming.corpusdesc , a.corpusimageids = incoming.corpusimageids , a.rocf1 = incoming.rocf1 , a.rocf2 = incoming.rocf2 , a.rocf3 = incoming.rocf3 , a.rocc1 = incoming.rocc1 , a.rocc2 = incoming.rocc2 , a.rocc3 = incoming.rocc3 , a.corpusactive = incoming.corpusactive , a.corpusrunfrequency = incoming.corpusrunfrequency , a.corpuslastrun = incoming.corpuslastrun , a.corpuslastsync = incoming.corpuslastsync , a.rocsettingid = incoming.rocsettingid , a.corpusaffinity = incoming.corpusaffinity , a.corpusterms = incoming.corpusterms , a.corpusdomain = incoming.corpusdomain " +
                              "WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN " +
                              "INSERT (corpusid, corpus_name, corpusdesc, corpusimageids, rocf1, rocf2, rocf3, rocc1, rocc2, rocc3, corpusactive, corpusrunfrequency, corpuslastrun, corpuslastsync, rocsettingid, corpusaffinity, corpusterms, corpusdomain) " +
                              "VALUES (incoming.corpusid, incoming.corpus_name, incoming.corpusdesc, incoming.corpusimageids, incoming.rocf1, incoming.rocf2, incoming.rocf3, incoming.rocc1, incoming.rocc2, incoming.rocc3, incoming.corpusactive, incoming.corpusrunfrequency, incoming.corpuslastrun, incoming.corpuslastsync, incoming.rocsettingid, incoming.corpusaffinity, incoming.corpusterms, incoming.corpusdomain)");
```

you have the create table in the question section, hope it helps someone! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Oracle then you'll need to focus on the `MERGE` statement - the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` doesn't work in Oracle.

I don't know if this is the only problem, but there are some syntax errors in the `MERGE` you posted:

```
MERGE INTO dev_corpus a
USING (SELECT * FROM dual WHERE (corpusid=?, corpus_name=?, corpuslastsync=?)
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ (1)
ON (a.corpusid = incoming.corpusid )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET (a.corpus_name = incoming.corpus_name AND a.corpuslastsync = incoming.corpuslastsync )
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ (2)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (a.corpusid, a.corpus_name, a.corpuslastsync)
VALUES (incoming.corpusid, incoming.corpus_name, incoming.corpuslastsync)
```

---

Problem (1): you have an unclosed parenthesis, plus the multiple `WHERE` conditions should be separated by `AND`, not a comma. Here's the corrected version, indented so it doesn't require horizontal scrolling:

```
USING (
  SELECT * FROM dual
  WHERE (corpusid=? AND corpus_name=? AND corpuslastsync=?))
```

The parentheses surrounding the `WHERE` conditions are optional in this case, so this would work too:

```
USING (
  SELECT * FROM dual
  WHERE corpusid=? AND corpus_name=? AND corpuslastsync=?)
```

---

Problem (2): The parentheses after the `SET`, and here you need the comma instead of the `AND`. It should look like this (as above, I've indented this so it can be read without horizontal scrolling)

```
UPDATE SET
  a.corpus_name = incoming.corpus_name,
  a.corpuslastsync = incoming.corpuslastsync
```

That should take care of any syntax errors, but of course that's no guarantee your results will be as expected :)

Finally, as I mentioned in the comments, try this out in SQLPlus or SQL Developer using test values (not parameters). It'll be much, much easier to debug that way. When you've got the `MERGE` behaving correctly you can move it to the Java code and parameterize it. Best of luck!

---

**Addendum for the updated question**

First of all, good news you're using SQL Developer to work this out! Disregard my last paragraph above :)

Second, your where includes `AND corpuslastsync = null`. When checking for null, you need `IS NULL`, not `= NULL`:

```
... AND corpuslastsync IS NULL
```

Finally, I'm pretty sure the specific error you're getting with your latest attempt is due to the aliases on this line:

```
INSERT (a.corpusid, a.corpus_name, a.corpuslastsync)
```

Try this instead:

```
INSERT (corpusid, corpus_name, corpuslastsync)
```

Oracle knows that the columns named here belong to the `dev_corpus` table, aliased as `a`.

Comment: thank you so much.but still doesnt work :(. plz see the edited question

Comment: Can you try removing the `a.` aliases on the `UPDATE` part? Instead of `SET a.corpusid = incoming.corpusid, etc` try `SET corpusid = incoming.corpusid`.

Comment: thans again but still doesnt work, another error though, plz see the edited query.

Comment: Getting there! The new error is because you're selecting from `DUAL` on the second line, and `DUAL` doesn't have column `corpusdomain` or any of the others in your `SELECT` list.

Comment: ok,but how can I set the variables then? especially for null ones?

Comment: I have tried this pattern SELECT 1000156 corpusid, from  [link](https://blogs.oracle.com/cmar/entry/using_merge_to_do_an)  doesnt work!

Comment: The content at the link looks solid, though I'd strip the aliases as we've done here. And you'd definitely select from `DUAL` in this case. You want something like this (partial example!): `... USING (SELECT 12345 corpusid, 'The name' corpus_name, 'The desc' corpusdesc FROM DUAL WHERE ...)`

Comment: Gibb: thank you sooo much! now it works in command win, but when I put in java class it only works in insertion cases not in Update cases!! really weired! The only thing I did was to replace the values in select with '?' (as said in the link). I put the query in question.

Comment: I'm out of practice with Java, so I'm afraid I can't help with that. A general pointer: are you catching exceptions and displaying them? The `MERGE` will execute either the `INSERT` or the `UPDATE`, so if the `INSERT` is working and `UPDATE` isn't, that means the `UPDATE is hitting a runtime error. This generally happens when there's bad data such as improperly-assigned NULL values, string instead of number, etc. Displaying the exception's message will usually point to the problem.

Comment: yes I catch and print the stacktrace but it freezes on pstmt.execute(), I am using the same data/values for update and insert for the exactly same row. so If there is a problem with the data in update it should acuure for insert as well, or am I wrong?

Comment: OK, this is weird, I should close the Oracle SQL developer and it works perfectly in java too! Thank you @Ed Gibb with ur help I made it! ;)

Comment: You're right - that is weird :) I'm glad you figured this out; it would never have occurred to me. Well done!