# How to write "INSERT IF EXISTS UPDATE" in Oracle using JAVA

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have a ERROR_MSG table which stores error messages with some ids. I want to insert error message if id is not present in table and if its present update error message. Inserting using below java JDBC code.

```
ID ERROR_MSG
1  ERR1
2  ERR2
3  ERR3
```

This is my code:

```
insertQry = "SQL";
Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement stmt = null;
try {
    con = getDataSource().getConnection();
    stmt = con.prepareStatement(insertQry);
    for(ListingAckNackData errorList: listOfListingERROR) {
        stmt.setLong(1, eqGlobalData.getSrcMsgId());
        stmt.setString(2, errorList.getGliId());
        if (null != errorList.getListingRevisionNo()) {
            stmt.setInt(3, errorList.getListingRevisionNo());
        } else {
            stmt.setNull(3, Types.NULL);
        }
        if (null != errorList.getErrorMessage()) {
            stmt.setString(4, errorList.getErrorMessage());
        } else {
            stmt.setNull(4, Types.NULL);
        }
        stmt.addBatch();
    }
    stmt.executeBatch();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle: how to UPSERT (update or insert into a table?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237327/oracle-how-to-upsert-update-or-insert-into-a-table), because I don't believe this is possible in a simple `INSERT OR UPDATE` query with Oracle.

Comment: Note that this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4015306/4391450) provide a simpler solution in Java but will cost some processing...

Comment: @AxelH how i can use the if with JAVA ?

Comment: What do you mean by "_the if_" ?

Comment: UPDATE tablename
    SET val1 = in_val1,
        val2 = in_val2
    WHERE val3 = in_val3;

IF ( sql%rowcount = 0 )
    THEN
    INSERT INTO tablename
        VALUES (in_val1, in_val2, in_val3);
END IF;  how to write this in string insertQry for java code above.

Comment: You should consider using named parameters like :paramName to prevent mixed parameter ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution in JAVA is to check if the row exist.

You start by getting a row count for the specific `id` you want to insert/update

```
select count('a') as rowExist from table where id = ?
```

Then, based on the result, you can easily create your query

```
if(rowExist > 0){
    query = "update ..";
else
    query = "insert ...";
```

Note that the parameters are probably not in the same order as you expect, you need to create the `insert` in the correct order to have the `id` at the end (since `update` need a `where` clause)

```
insert into Table (name, birthday, id) values (?, ?, ?)
update Table set name = ?, birthday = ? where id = ?
```

Comment: For that two sql are needed, i want it in single sql, it is not possible in ORACLE ?

Comment: @ArpanPaliwal It is possible if you use a stored procedure that you called from Java using a `Callable`. For that, check the duplicate. There is no need to rewrite the solution here, since everything will be done in a store proc on the DB. You just need to create a `Callable` to call that procedure.

Comment: can't use store proc for a small change thanks for above solution.

Comment: With this solution you have to think about transaction handling. Otherwise multiple threads may insert duplicates or run into exceptions if a matching constraint exists.

Comment: Isn't having a single `MERGE` statement that handles both better than having two hits on database?

Comment: I wasn't aware of the MERGE, it seems most efficient as everything is done in one call, but this is providing a lot of information, so a bit more messy in the prepared statement in JAVA. As an example with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17705576/oracle-merge-and-prepared-statement) using a merge. Thanks for the knowldge @AyushKumar

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to run a database statement as questioned. Simply use SQL command MERGE INTO... IF NOT MATCHED INSERT... IF MATCHED UPDATE ...
You will find an full example and documentation [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/merge-statement).